# How to fix issue in running an API with forward slashes ("/") in its id path parameter using ApiBuilder Java

Tags: java, rest, kotlin

I am using `ApiBuilder` in Java where my `id` path param has forward slashes (`"/"`) because of encryption. However, the endpoint is not being found when run because the slashes are read as part of the URL, not as the id. Here is how I call the API request:

```java
ApiBuilder.post("http://localhost:5008/api/update/{id}") {
// code process here
}
```

The sample id value is:

> mxCSRO3qErTy7eO77HJeUvBiKXM/1i1cd3GdHuqdeSz/lyLU/N7cBCz3eZoIUyybhhmpAeJ1IABomr8Kv0IDKA==

Edit: I have already solved the issue here. According to javalin documentation, the path should be *less_than*id*greater_than* instead of `{id}`.

Comment: have you tried using 'URLEncoder.encode' ?

Comment: That's not encryption. It's base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
String idValue = "mxCSRO3qErTy7eO77HJeUvBiKXM/1i1cd3GdHuqdeSz/lyLU/N7cBCz3eZoIUyybhhmpAeJ1IABomr8Kv0IDKA==";
String encodedId = URLEncoder.encode(idValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

String apiUrl = "http://localhost:5008/api/update/" + encodedId;
```

Use the uri like this,

And you can later modify your endpoint like this-

```
ApiBuilder.post(apiUrl) {
    // code process here
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! one of my problems is also how can I read the idValue from the url because the idValue must be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all slashes (`/`) with `%2F` yourself.
Here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to the encoding reference.

Or use this

```java
    URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)
```

- **s** — String to be translated.
- **enc** — The name of a supported character encoding.

Example:

```
        private fun getUrl(): String {
             val idValue = "mxCSRO3qErTy7eO77HJeUvBiKXM/1i1cd3GdHuqdeSz/lyLU/N7cBCz3eZoIUyybhhmpAeJ1IABomr8Kv0IDKA=="
             val encodedId = URLEncoder.encode(idValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
             return "http://localhost:5008/api/update/$encodedId"
       }
```

Comment: how can i read the id from the url using ApiBuilder? the idValue must be dynamic

Comment: In your question, in the code example, you write that you are passing an ID. That means you're getting it from somewhere, right?

Comment: in javalin, you can use {id} in reading the id in a url path. but i think it doesn't consider forward slashes as an id

Comment: nevermind, i have already solved the problem. as per the document, i should have coded <id> instead of {id} to ignore slashes. thank you so much for answering